# Anylogic "Block" creation in a flow chart undoing in my model

Tags: modeling, anylogic

I have selected a group of items in my Any logic simulation modal and then after right clicking i have created new flow chart Block....i want to undo the same and want to see the detailed flow chart instead...!
Please don't suggest the "double click" as i already tried but i want the detailed flow chart in the main model itself not in a separate window.

in short my issue is "H**ow to undo a Block which i have created in my anylogic model**"???

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply Undo using either ctrl+z on Windows or cmd+z on Mac, or from the edit menu

[image]

But if these are no longer available you can simply go into your newly created block (either double click where it is in Main or enter it from the projects tab) and copy the insides and paste them back where you want them... and then you can delete the block from the Projects Toolbar.

There is no programmatically undo, you will have to copy and paste the inside yourself.

Comment: There is no programmatically undo, you will have to copy and paste the inside yourself......that is it.                                  Thnx vosloo bhai

Comment: Thank you @ManishChoudhary, if you found my answer helpful remember to accept it so that others can benefit from it and upvote it if you found it worthy ;-)

Comment: accepted. However i m not able to upvote it as it says "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."